# How to read columns of a hive partitioned parquet file in python?

Tags: python, parquet

Generally you read the schema of a parquet file like:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
sch = pq.read_schema(path+filename, memory_map=True)
```

But this does not work for hive partitioned files.
Tried adding the

```
partitioning='hive'
```

option, but it is not implemented.
How do I get the columns / schema of such a file?

Comment: I guess you mean a directory partition structure, not a single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.schema`:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pa.table(
    {
        "col1": pa.array(['a', 'a', 'b'], pa.string()),
        "col2": pa.array([1, 2, 3], pa.int32()),
    }
)

pq.write_to_dataset(
    table,
    "./dataset",
    ['col1']
)

schema = pq.ParquetDataset("./dataset").schema
```

But you may have bad surprises because `write_to_dataset` doesn't write any meta data. So `ParquetDataset` has to guess the schema from the first parquet file it can find. It also has a hard time figuring out the type of the partition columns.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I'm doing a scan_pyarrow_dataset on the file and get back the columns from that:

```
import polars as pl
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
data = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(ds.dataset(parq_path+file, partitioning='hive'))
print(data.columns)
```